# Default direct sound does not play any sound but video is playing while capture

Tags: c#, directshow

I'm using codeproject sample for capture live tv, everything is ok but sound does not play!

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/822703/Features-of-DVB-T-application-development-using-Cs) is codeproject url and here is my code:

```
private void BuildVideoAndAudioPins()
    {
        //  Setup video pin media type
        var videoPinType = new AMMediaType
        {
            majorType = MediaType.Video,
            subType = MediaSubType.H264,
            formatType = FormatType.VideoInfo2
        };
        IPin videoPin;
        var hr = ((IMpeg2Demultiplexer)mpeg2Demux).CreateOutputPin(videoPinType, "Video", out videoPin);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        // Setup audio pin media type
        var audioPinType = new AMMediaType
        {
            majorType = MediaType.Audio,
            subType = MediaSubType.Mpeg2Audio,
            sampleSize = 65536,
            temporalCompression = false,
            fixedSizeSamples = true, // or false in MediaPortal //true
            unkPtr = IntPtr.Zero,
            formatType = FormatType.WaveEx
        };

        // We need to set up FormatPtr for proper connection to decoder filter
        var mpeg1WaveFormat = new MPEG1WaveFormat
        {
            wfx = new DirectShowLib.WaveFormatEx
            {

                wFormatTag = 0x0050,
                nChannels = 2,
                nSamplesPerSec = 48000,
                nAvgBytesPerSec = 32000,
                nBlockAlign = 768,
                wBitsPerSample = 0,
                cbSize = 22 // extra size

            },
            fwHeadLayer = AcmMpegHeadLayer.Layer2,
            //dwHeadBitrate = 0x00177000,
            fwHeadMode = AcmMpegHeadMode.SingleChannel,
            fwHeadModeExt = 1,
            wHeadEmphasis = 1,
            fwHeadFlags = AcmMpegHeadFlags.OriginalHome | AcmMpegHeadFlags.IDMpeg1,
            dwPTSLow = 0,
            dwPTSHigh = 0
        };
        audioPinType.formatSize = Marshal.SizeOf(mpeg1WaveFormat);
        audioPinType.formatPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(audioPinType.formatSize);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(mpeg1WaveFormat, audioPinType.formatPtr, false);

        IPin audioPin;
        hr = ((IMpeg2Demultiplexer)mpeg2Demux).CreateOutputPin(audioPinType, "Audio", out audioPin);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
    }

private void AddAudioFilters()
    {
        // Microsoft buitin audio decoder
        audioDecoder = FilterGraphTools.AddFilterByName(graphBuilder, FilterCategory.LegacyAmFilterCategory, "Microsoft DTV-DVD Audio Decoder");
        if (audioDecoder == null)
            throw new Exception("Failed to create audio decoder");
        FilterGraphTools.ConnectFilters(graphBuilder, DsFindPin.ByName(mpeg2Demux, "Audio"), DsFindPin.ByDirection(audioDecoder, PinDirection.Input, 0), true);

        // Standard DirectSound output
        audioRenderer = FilterGraphTools.AddFilterByName(graphBuilder, FilterCategory.AudioRendererCategory, "Default DirectSound Device");
        FilterGraphTools.ConnectFilters(graphBuilder, DsFindPin.ByDirection(audioDecoder, PinDirection.Output, 0), DsFindPin.ByDirection(audioRenderer, PinDirection.Input, 0), false);


    }
```

I think the problem is in audio header as well as code project describe!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? If you are capturing, you are not playing sound.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i mean everything is ok but i dont hear any sound of tv or radio, how can i implant aoudio pin automaticly not manulay?

Comment: If you want to hear what you are capturing, you need to insert an Infinite Pin Tee Filter and connect one output to an Audio Renderer. If you also want to hear the audio before you start the capture, you have to use something like [GMFBridge](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/gmfbridge/)

Comment: thanks but unfortunatly this is not my problem! i cant hear any sound of tv channel, i dont want to use this method BuildVideoAndAudioPins() , instead i'd like to automatically add audio ping without this methods information